# Como eu faço esse painel com sistema de grid bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, grid

Galera estou com muita dificuldade em fazer um dashboard sales eu sei usar o sistema grid do bootstrap mas nesse projeto que eu preciso fazer a class row tem tamanho de altura e alinha com as outras grid vou postar um exemplo aqui

https://www.geckoboard.com/learn/dashboard-examples/salesforce-dashboard-example/live-dashboard/#.V7Z8xstv_qA

Quero fazer dashboard igual esse mas usando sistema de grid do bootstrap  como eu faço na questão do tamanho das row e col "top sdr"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como você não disse se vai ser dinamico ou nao, a quantidade de blocos, considerei uma quantidade fixa igual a do exemplo.

Mas acredito que o segredo é definir um tamanho minimo nos blocos, os que sao maiores, basicamente usa o valor minimo como base e considera tambem o tamanho dos margins top e bottom que eventualmente pode ter.

Fiz um exemplo bem basico, mas acho que ja é um ponto de partida.

```css
.row div {
    min-height: 133px;
}

.margin-top {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.margin-bottom {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.margin-left {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.margin-right {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#col1 .row div {
    background: #F00;
}

#col1-1 {
    height: 276px; /* 133 da altura de cada div + 20 das 2 margins da coluna do meio */
}

#col2 .row div {
    background: #0F0;
    height: 133px;
}

#col3 .row div {
    background: #00F;
}

#col3-0 {
    height: 276px /* mesma coisa de #col1-1 */;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4" id="col1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 margin-bottom" id="col1-1">1.0</div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">1.1</div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">1.2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6" id="col2">
            <div class="row margin-bottom">
                <div class="col-xs-8">2.0</div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">2.1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row margin-bottom">
                <div class="col-xs-4">2.2</div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">2.3</div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">2.4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">2.5</div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">2.6</div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">2.7</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2" id="col3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 margin-bottom" id="col3-0">3.0</div>
                <div class="col-xs-12" id="col3-1">3.1</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nossa ficou perfeito obrigado :D